# how do I set the webhook URL via the API

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

How do I set the webhook URL via the dialog flow API V2.  I am pulling all of the intents / entities and setting them up using the c# SDK but I cant see how I set the webhook programatically and enable the webhook property in the Fulfillment page

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the intents, in order to interact with the webhook fulfillment setting, you need to use the [WebhookState](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.Intent.html#Google_Cloud_Dialogflow_V2_Intent_WebhookState) property. You can set it to one of the following:

- Enabled
- EnabledForSlotFilling
- Unspecified

Regarding enabling Webhook Fulfillment at agent level. I found an [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142495717#comment2) where is described how to enable it with the Rest API; however, even though it seems that updating this setting is supported, the documentation doesn't mention it, and it is not implemented by the C# library. So, I think that doing it with the Dialogflow UI is the most straightforward approach.

Comment: thanks you so much for taking the time to help - much appreciated